# Issue while installing Solr with Sitecore MVC 7.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, solr, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

I am trying to install SOLR 4.5.1 with sitecore mvc 7.1.

I am having issues while I am trying to run the admin section.

Below is the detailed error message, anyone who have issue resolution please help:

I did check that the missing files does exist at the mentioned location but since this is my first install I might be wrong.

```
 HTTP Status 500 - {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'lang/stopwords_ro.txt' in classpath or 'C:\solr\collection1\conf/', 
cwd=C:\tomcat,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'lang/stopwords_ro.txt' in classpath or 'C:\solr\collection1\conf/', cwd=C:\tomcat at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:783) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:295) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'lang/stopwords_ro.txt' in classpath or 'C:\solr\collection1\conf/', cwd=C:\tomcat at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:169) at 
org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.create(IndexSchemaFactory.java:55) at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.buildIndexSchema(IndexSchemaFactory.java:69) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:519) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:557) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:247) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:239) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ... 3 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'lang/stopwords_ro.txt' in classpath or 'C:\solr\collection1\conf/', cwd=C:\tomcat at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:322) at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AbstractAnalysisFactory.getLines(AbstractAnalysisFactory.java:255) at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AbstractAnalysisFactory.getWordSet(AbstractAnalysisFactory.java:243) at 
org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopFilterFactory.inform(StopFilterFactory.java:66) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:625) at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:167) ... 12 more ,code=500}
```

---

**type Status report**

```
     message {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'lang/stopwords_ro.txt' in classpath or 'C:\solr\collection1\conf/',
     cwd=C:\tomcat,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'lang/stopwords_ro.txt' in classpath or 'C:\solr\collection1\conf/', cwd=C:\tomcat at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:783) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:295) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) at 
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'lang/stopwords_ro.txt' in classpath or 'C:\solr\collection1\conf/', cwd=C:\tomcat at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:169) at 
    org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.create(IndexSchemaFactory.java:55) at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.buildIndexSchema(IndexSchemaFactory.java:69) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:519) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:557) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:247) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:239) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ... 3 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'lang/stopwords_ro.txt' in classpath or 'C:\solr\collection1\conf/', cwd=C:\tomcat at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:322) at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AbstractAnalysisFactory.getLines(AbstractAnalysisFactory.java:255) at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AbstractAnalysisFactory.getWordSet(AbstractAnalysisFactory.java:243) at 
    org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopFilterFactory.inform(StopFilterFactory.java:66) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:625) at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:167) ... 12 more ,code=500}
```

> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.

---

> Apache Tomcat/7.0.47

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `schema.xml` file references stop word files that are missing from the `/conf` folder. Open your schema.xml file and search for `stopwords` in it. Find the references and see if you're missing any. If so, simply copy missing files to your `/conf` folder. Some of them could be located in `/conf/lang` directory.

As a side note, consider using forward slashes ('/') for paths in your configuration files. You can avoid many problems by following that rule with Java apps.